# Converting an Access Query with IIF to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I am looking for a bit of help converting an access query into sql server.

Most of it i fine with but i am struggling with the IIF part

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (([if_submission] 
     LEFT JOIN [payrollruns] 
            ON [if_submission].[periodnumber] = [payrollruns].[runid]) 
    LEFT JOIN [if_rti_finalfps_q] 
           ON [payrollruns].[runid] = [if_rti_finalfps_q].[runid]) 
   LEFT JOIN [if_rti_eps] 
          ON [if_submission].[submissionid] = [if_rti_eps].[submissionid] 
WHERE  [if_submission].[taxyear] = 2016 
   AND ( **IIF([if_submission].[submissiontypeid] = 8, 
         [payrollruns].[payemonth] = 5, 
               [if_submission].[periodnumber] = 5)** ) 
   AND ( [if_submission].[submissiontypeid] = 8 
          OR [if_submission].[submissiontypeid] = 10 ) 
   AND [if_submission].[testinlive] = 0 
ORDER  BY submissiontypeid
```

This is the bit i need help with

```
IIF([if_submission].[submissiontypeid] = 8, 
         [payrollruns].[payemonth] = 5, 
               [if_submission].[periodnumber] = 5)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that worked in MS Access?  That looks like a really odd way of using `iif`.

Comment: Yep definitely works for Access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
AND 5 = CASE WHEN [if_submission].[submissiontypeid] = 8 
          THEN [payrollruns].[payemonth]
          ELSE [if_submission].[periodnumber]
        END
```

Comment: Thanks, just what i needed.  Spent ages looking around and couldn't find anything that matched this answer, must have been looking for the wrong thing!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`CASE` expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

> Simple CASE expression:
>
> ```
> CASE input_expression   
>     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
>     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
> END
> ```
>
> Searched CASE expression:
>
> ```
> CASE  
>     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ]   
>     [ ELSE else_result_expression ]   
> END
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+` then `IIF` is supported, but syntax need to be little different.

```
IIF([if_submission].[submissiontypeid] = 8,[payrollruns].[payemonth],
                                           [if_submission].[periodnumber] ) = 5
```

else I will do this using `AND/OR` logic

```
......
(
(
[if_submission].[submissiontypeid] = 8 and [payrollruns].[payemonth] = 5
) 
or 
(
[if_submission].[periodnumber] = 5 and [if_submission].[submissiontypeid] <> 8
)
)
.....
```